# jQuery Validation plugin with live "click"

Tags: jquery-validate, jquery

I have have a site where the user can alter the page content using `jquery load`. In each page content I have a form which I validate with `jquery validation plugin`

```
    $("#form-create").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            save(name);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I have noticed that all jquery `click` functions only work until I change the page content but I solved it with replacing the `click` with `live "click"`. Though the same problemm occurs with the above validation. How come using `click` works until I altered the page content and `live "click"` solves the problem? OR how can I use the validation plugin with `live "click"` ,which will solve the problem, but not explain it to me :)

Comment: When you set up a normal `click` event, then this is attached to every existing element. When you change the page content by loading/creating new elements, these elements do not get the same events. The `live` function keeps checking for new matching elements to attach the same `click` event to, so it does not matter if you change the page content. Unfortunately I don't know how to incorporate `validate` into your setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that live click solves your problem is that the elements didn't originally exist on your DOM, so using "live" means it's a live click regardless due to it refreshing as new elements arrive on the DOM. The default events only use the first DOM that was loaded.

If you want to check validate through the live click event then you should use something like this:

```
$('.submitButton').live("click", function() {

    $("#form-create").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            save(name);
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Hope this helps, it was a little difficult as you didn't specify *which* validation plugin you're using, however, whatever the plugin this should work assuming you wish to call the validation on the submit button click event.

Comment: I use the [validate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin. Your solution worked but if I have two fields with `class="required"` and the validate() plugin only validates the first required field and the error-class appears on click only if the second field has been focused once and also gets hidden if I click submit again. Strange bugs, does it come with the live-solution?

Comment: Still dont know why above doesnt work but I used the `rules` instead and that works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you bind a set of elements, say `$("div.clickable")`, with an event, the set is resolved with the DOM at the time of the execution of the $() function. All succeeding elements (appearing after that moment) won't be bound because they didn't belongs to the original set

Live does exactly this : it refreshes the original set as new element appears, then new elements are bound as they appear in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no load event in live, although this is being [asked](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/add-support-for-load-and-ready-events-in-live) for quite some time.

You can go around this by placing a callback function in your ajax calls. This can be done globally using [global ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/):

```
$('#contentDiv').ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#form-create").validate(validateOptions);
});
```